# Run a function in between each iteration of fsolve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization

I am using [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fsolve.html) to minimise an energy function in MATLAB. The algorithm I am using fits a grid to noisy lattice data, with costs for the distances of the grid from each data point.

The objective function is formulated with squared error terms, to allow for the [Gauss–Newton algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) to be used. However, the program reverts to Levenberg-Marquardt:

```
Warning: Trust-region-dogleg algorithm of FSOLVE cannot handle non-square systems;
using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm instead.
```

I realised this is probably due to the fact that while the costs have squared errors, there is a stage in the objective (cost) function that chooses the nearest grid centre to each data point, thus making the algorithm non-square.

What I would like to do is to perform this assignment update of nearest grid centres separately to the evaluation of the Jacobian of the cost function. I believe this would then allow Gauss-Newton to be used, and significantly improve the speed of the algorithm.

Currently, I believe there is something like this going on:

```
while i < options.MaxIter && threshold has not been met
    Compute Jacobian of cost function (which includes assignment routine)
    Move down the slope in the direction of highest gradient
end
```

What i would like to happen instead:

```
while i < options.MaxIter && threshold has not been met
    Perform assignment routine
    Compute Jacobian of cost function (which is now square, as no assignment occurs)
    Move down the slope
end
```

Is there a way to insert a function like this into the iterations without picking apart the whole of the `fsolve` algorithm? Even if I manually edited fsolve, would the nature of the Gauss-Newton algorithm allow me to add in this extra step?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with squared errors, anyway, you could use [LSQNONLIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) instead of `fsovle`. This allows you to compute the Jacobian (as well as all necessary preparations) in your objective function. The Jacobian is then returned as second output argument.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It performs much better than the default fsolve algorithm straight out of the box, and I suspect that when I get round to sorting out my own Jacobian the time savings will come in big time. Cheers

Comment: @Bill Cheatham: You may also be interested in looking at @woodchips' [optimization tips and tricks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8553-optimization-tips-and-tricks), which includes `pleas.m`, and algorithm for partitioned least squares. If you have both linear and nonlinear unknowns, this algorithm can make a massive difference in terms of speed and stability.